# boost::optional 使用時のコンパイルエラー 'value_type' is a protected member of 'boost::optional_detail::optional_base<my_template_class<my_class>>'

Tags: c++, boost

アプリ制作のためにXcodeでC++を使っています。boost::optionalを使用していますが、

> '...' is a protected member of
>   'boost::optional_detail::optional_base>'

というエラーが8個出ます。...は、以下のtypedefのvalue_type, reference_type, ... にあたります。

```
template<class T>
class optional : public optional_detail::optional_base<T>
{
    typedef optional_detail::optional_base<T> base ;

  public :

    typedef optional<T> this_type ;

    typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME base::value_type           value_type ;
    typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME base::reference_type       reference_type ;
    typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME base::reference_const_type reference_const_type ;
#ifndef  BOOST_NO_CXX11_RVALUE_REFERENCES
    typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME base::rval_reference_type  rval_reference_type ;
    typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME base::reference_type_of_temporary_wrapper reference_type_of_temporary_wrapper ;
#endif
    typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME base::pointer_type         pointer_type ;
    typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME base::pointer_const_type   pointer_const_type ;
    typedef BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME base::argument_type        argument_type ;
```

また、my_template_classですが、

```
template<class T> class my_template_class
{
private:
  T member_;
  ...
}
```

という風に定義されていて、

> Field has incomplete type 'テンプレート引数に入れたクラス名'

というコンパイルエラーも出ています。どのように解決すればよいでしょうか。

Comment: `incomplete type` は、例えば、`data[]` のようなサイズが指定されていないフィールドがあるということです。（つまり、サイズが決定できない=>メモリイメージが決定できない）

Comment: 初歩的な質問で申し訳ありませんでした。解決致しました。
std::shared_ptrを使用していたものをboost::optionalに変更した時に起きたので、Tの型のサイズが決定できなくなってしまったことが問題でした。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コメントと同じものですが、ここに書かさせていただきます。
std::shared_ptrを使用していたものをboost::optionalに変更した時に起きたので、Tの型のサイズが決定できなくなってしまったことが問題で‌​した。ありがとうございました。